# Is there a way to set a limit to Excel's maximum row limit of 1,048,576

Tags: excel, vba

I noticed through a mistake when completing an excel task that the maximum row limit is 1,048,576. Is there a setting or some VBA that can limit an excel workbook to have a maximum row limit of less than 1,048,576?

For example, lets say I have a workbook that really would never go above 2,000 records. Is there a way to set it so that no matter what, a record greater than number 2,000 could not exist?

Looked all over online, could only see users wanting to increase the limit!

Comment: Perhaps protect any rows greater than 2000?

Comment: @BigBen Good point, apologies if it was a silly question

Comment: I wonder how that might affect the `UsedRange` and possibly the file size though.

Comment: Also inserting rows / shifting existing rows down will shift the protected cells down, so it's probably more complicated than that. Depends how the content is being added to the worksheet, I guess. Definitely not a silly question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to protect (and optionally hide) all rows past 2000. As regards the concerns raised in the excellent comments:

- When protecting the sheet, disallow inserting new rows.
- The protected rows are not included in the sheet's `.UsedRange`.
- In testing, the file size only increased by several KB, so no concerns there.